# HTML Form to ExtJS Form

Tags: forms, extjs, field

I have an html form in which the fields are extremely scattered. The page has been created using html table - rowspan and colspan combinations.

I need to convert this form to ExtJS and display it in a window.

After carrying out some research, I feel that table layout could be best choice for positioning the fields. But there are few issues which I have been facing as following:

1. If I give rowspan or colspan as 2 or more, then also the fields don't increase in size to occupy the availabe space and remain confined to single column.
2. If I resize the window, then the table doesn't resize (though, the form does as the tbar present at the top expand to occupy the complete space).

I have used the layout as 'fit' for window and layout as 'table' for the form.

I have also tried using 'anchor' layout for form and then having a fieldset with table layout, but the positioning didn't work.

Could someone please throw some light on this. Following is a basic code snippet I am using:

```
var form    =   Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                                    url:'voyage_berth_monitoring.php',
                                    fieldDefaults: {
                                        labelAlign: 'right'
                                    },
                                    layout:{
                                        type:'table',
                                        columns:3
                                    },
                                    defaults:{
                                        anchor:'100%'
                                    },
                                    tbar:[
                                        {
                                            xtype:'button',
                                            text:'Clear'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype:'button',
                                            text:'Delete'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype:'tbfill'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype:'button',
                                            text:'Save'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype:'button',
                                            text:'Exit'
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    items: [


                                                {
                                                        fieldLabel:'item',
                                                        xtype:'textfield'

                                                },
                                                {
                                                        fieldLabel:'item',
                                                        xtype:'textfield',
                                                        colspan:2

                                                },
                                                {
                                                        fieldLabel:'item',
                                                        xtype:'textfield'

                                                },
                                                {
                                                        fieldLabel:'item',
                                                        xtype:'textfield'

                                                },
                                                {
                                                        fieldLabel:'item',
                                                        xtype:'textfield'

                                                }


                                    ]
                                });



var win =   Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                            title: 'Window',
                            closable: true,
                            closeAction:'hide',
                            minimizable:true,
                            maximizable:true,
                            height:350,
                            width:750,
                            layout:'fit',
                            autoScroll:true,
                            items: form
                        });

win.show();
```

Comment: Already look at: `http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/dynamic.html` Form 3 will be helpful. Also you can render top to viewport:    `Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
     layout: 'fit',
     items: [top],
     renderTo: Ext.getBody()
 });`

Comment: Thanks for the help Xupypr. I had tried it, but this structure too doesn't allow the flexibility as its there in the table tag of html, where we can have control over every section of page. Moreover, using alot of containers for desired positioning in the page makes it a bit complicated too. Is such flexibility not possible through the table layout of extjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicly i had the same problem with the layout table, couldn't find any way to span my displayfields to the length of the td, and also the same issue with the 2 columns field.

The solution i prefered was to extend the table layout and give it that flexibility

```
Ext.define('Extended.TableLayout', {
    alias:'layout.extendedTable',
    extend: 'Ext.layout.container.Table',
    type: 'extendedTable',
    columns: 2,
    rightMargin: 20,
    tableAttrs:{
        width: '100%'
    },
    tdAttrs:{
        width:'50%'
    },
    itemCls:'x-table-cell',
    renderItems: function(items) {

        var totalWidth = this.getLayoutTargetSize().width,
            len = items.length,
            i, item, colNr;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            item = items[i];

                colNr = this.columns;
            if ((colNr > 1) && Ext.isNumber(item.colspan)) {
                colNr = colNr - item.colspan + 1;
            }
            item.width = Math.floor(totalWidth/colNr) - this.rightMargin;
        }
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Using the extendedTable layout i get the desired look

Comment: Extension is excellent Nscrob. Thanks for sharing it. Though, I served my purpose by using a combination of column and hbox layouts. But would definitely likely to lay a hand on what you have created for future applications.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative it to serialize your HTML form data as JSON and load it into an EXT store. Once it's in a store, EXT will happily do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks Diodeus, but doing so probably breaches the rule of separating "view" part from the rest of application.